# Returning 2 different arrays using the same random variable

Tags: php, arrays, return

I am trying to use return 2 different arrays using the same random variable.  So I have:

```
function TransTest() {
    $TransQ = array();
    $TransA = array();

    $TransQ[0] = "Q1";
    $TransQ[1] = "Q2";
    $TransQ[2] = "Q3";
    $TransQ[3] = "Q4";    

    $TransA[0] = "Ans 1";
    $TransA[1] = "Ans 2";
    $TransA[2] = "Ans 3";
    $TransA[3] = "Ans 4";    

    $index = rand(0, count($TransQ)-1);

    return $TransQ[$index];
}
```

So this basically returns a random Question from the `$TransQ` array.  What I would like to do is return the respective answer to the question.

Something similar to:

```
return ($TransQ[$index] && $TransA[$index]);
```

But this doesn't seem to work.  Please help.

Comment: `return ['Question' => $TransQ[$index], 'Answer' => $TransA[$index]];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return an array:

```
return array($TransQ[$index], $TransA[$index]);
```

Then access:

```
$result = TransTest();
echo $result[0] . ' is ' . $result[1];
```

Or associative:

```
return array('q' => $TransQ[$index], 'a' => $TransA[$index]);
```

Then:

```
$result = TransTest();
echo $result['q'] . ' is ' . $result['a'];
```

Or in each of the above cases:

```
list($question, $answer) = TransTest();
echo $question . ' is ' . $answer;
```

Another way (probably not the best choice for your case), is to use references `&`:

```
function TransTest(&$q=null, &$a=null) {
    //code
    $q = $TransQ[$index];
    $a = $TransA[$index];
}
```

Then:

```
TransTest($question, $answer);
echo $question . ' is ' . $answer;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive answer, this works perfectly!  Appreciate the help!